# ClickHouse Union All exception

Tags: clickhouse

I wrote create view expression with union all.

```
create view if not exists V_REGRESULT as select 1                         AS jType,
                                                regF.smscid               AS SmscID,
                                                regF.eventdate            AS EventDate,
                                                regF.smppid               AS SmppID,
                                                regF.registereddate       AS RegisteredDate,
                                                regF.sendernpid           AS SenderNPid,
                                                regF.senderntid           AS SenderNTid,
                                                regF.senderdirectionid    AS SenderDirectionID,
                                                regF.CgPN                 AS CgPN,
                                                regF.OriginalCgPn         AS OriginalCgPN,
                                                regF.recipientnpid        AS RecipientNPid,
                                                regF.recipientntid        AS RecipientNTid,
                                                regF.recipientdirectionid AS RecipientDirectionID,
                                                regF.cdpn                 AS CdPN,
                                                regF.OriginalCdPn         AS OriginalCdPN,
                                                regF.ValidityPeriod       AS ValidityPeriod,
                                                regF.expireddate          AS ExpiredDate,
                                                regF.deliveryreporttypeid AS DeliveryReportTypeID,
                                                regF.umr                  AS Umr,
                                                regF.smtypeid             AS SmTypeID,
                                                regF.uhdiheaderinsm       AS UhdiHeaderInsm,
                                                regF.uhdisequenceid       AS UhdiSequenceID,
                                                regF.uhdipartstotal       AS UhdiPartsTotal,
                                                regF.uhdipartn            AS UhdiPartN,
                                                regF.setbackpath          AS SetBackPath,
                                                regF.smppencoding         AS SmppEncoding,
                                                regF.originalsmppencoding AS OriginalSmppEncoding,
                                                regF.retrycount           AS RetryCount,
                                                regF.retrycountsh         AS RetryCountsH,
                                                regF.schemeid             AS SchemeID,
                                                regF.lasterrortypeid      AS LastErrorTypeID,
                                                regF.lastneterror         AS LastNetError,
                                                regF.lastsmpperror        AS LastSmppError,
                                                regF.lastnativeerror      AS LastNativeError,
                                                regF.smstatusid           AS SmStatusID,
                                                regF.reportstatus         AS ReportStatus,
                                                regF.protocolid           AS ProtocolID,
                                                regF.modifiedprotocolid   AS ModifiedProtocolID,
                                                regF.dbencoding           AS DbEncoding,
                                                regF.messagelen           AS MessageLen,
                                                regF.smbody               AS SmBody,
                                                regF.senderserviceid      AS SenderServiceID,
                                                regF.recipientserviceid   AS RecipientServiceID,
                                                regF.imsi                 AS Imsi,
                                                regF.commutatorgt         AS CommutatorGT,
                                                regF.targetimsi           AS TargetImsi,
                                                regF.targetcommutatorgt   AS TargetCommutatorGT,
                                                regF.eventflag            AS EventFlag,
                                                regF.failcode             AS FailCode,
                                                regF.ScpGt                AS ScpGt,
                                                regF.ResultCode           AS ResultCode
                                         from SMCS.V_REGFAIL regF
                                         union all
                                         select 2                        AS jType,
                                                reg.SmscId               AS SmscID,
                                                reg.EventDate            AS EventDate,
                                                reg.SmppID               AS SmppID,
                                                reg.RegisteredDate       AS RegisteredDate,
                                                reg.SenderNPID           AS SenderNPid,
                                                reg.SenderNTID           AS SenderNTid,
                                                reg.SenderDirectionID    AS SenderDirectionID,
                                                reg.CgPN                 AS CgPN,
                                                reg.OriginalCgPN         AS OriginalCgPN,
                                                reg.RecipientNPid        AS RecipientNPid,
                                                reg.RecipientNTid        AS RecipientNTid,
                                                reg.RecipientDirectionID AS RecipientDirectionID,
                                                reg.CdPN                 AS CdPN,
                                                reg.OriginalCdPN         AS OriginalCdPN,
                                                reg.ValidityPeriod       AS ValidityPeriod,
                                                reg.ExpiredDate          AS ExpiredDate,
                                                reg.DeliveryReportTypeID AS DeliveryReportTypeID,
                                                reg.Umr                  AS Umr,
                                                reg.SmTypeID             AS SmTypeID,
                                                reg.UhdiHeaderInsm       AS UhdiHeaderInsm,
                                                reg.UhdiSequenceID       AS UhdiSequenceID,
                                                reg.UhdiPartsTotal       AS UhdiPartsTotal,
                                                reg.UhdiPartN            AS UhdiPartN,
                                                reg.SetBackPath          AS SetBackPath,
                                                reg.SmppEncoding         AS SmppEncoding,
                                                reg.OriginalSmppEncoding AS OriginalSmppEncoding,
                                                reg.RetryCount           AS RetryCount,
                                                reg.RetryCountsH         AS RetryCountsH,
                                                reg.SchemeID             AS SchemeID,
                                                reg.LastErrorTypeID      AS LastErrorTypeID,
                                                reg.LastNetError         AS LastNetError,
                                                reg.LastSmppError        AS LastSmppError,
                                                reg.LastNativeError      AS LastNativeError,
                                                reg.SmStatusID           AS SmStatusID,
                                                reg.ReportStatus         AS ReportStatus,
                                                reg.ProtocolID           AS ProtocolID,
                                                reg.ModifiedProtocolID   AS ModifiedProtocolID,
                                                reg.DbEncoding           AS DbEncoding,
                                                reg.MessageLen           AS MessageLen,
                                                reg.SmBody               AS SmBody,
                                                reg.SenderServiceID      AS SenderServiceID,
                                                reg.RecipientServiceID   AS RecipientServiceID,
                                                reg.Imsi                 AS Imsi,
                                                reg.CommutatorGT         AS CommutatorGT,
                                                reg.TargetImsi           AS TargetImsi,
                                                reg.TargetCommutatorGT   AS TargetCommutatorGT,
                                                ''                       AS EventFlag,
                                                ''                       AS FailCode,
                                                reg.ScpGt                AS ScpGt,
                                                ''                       AS ResultCode
                                         from SMCS.V_REGISTRATION reg
;
```

All columns in requested views exists. I haven't got any idea about this exception

```
Code: 386, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There is no supertype for types String, DateTime because some of them are String/FixedString and some of them are not (version 19.15.3.6 (official build))
```

Where could be there a mistake? Simple union like `select 1  as one union all select 2 as one` works good. The only thing i found was that error was caused due to Array Join, when type casting.

Initally, i was thinking that this was caused due to NULL casting at EventFlag, e.t.c, while union and replace NULL with ''. But nothing has changed

Help, pls

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: You should provide your create tables query as well. But there's incompatibility in types of those two selects, you can use `toTypeName()` to detect what differs. I suspect `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select now() union all select ''

Code: 386. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. 
DB::Exception: There is no supertype for types DateTime, String 
because some of them are String/FixedString and some of them are not.
```

cast to String

```
select toString(now()) union all select ''
┌─toString(now())─────┐
│ 2019-11-19 14:25:13 │
└─────────────────────┘
┌─toString(now())─┐
│                 │
└─────────────────┘
```

'cast' to DateTime

```
select now() union all select toDateTime(0)
┌───────────────now()─┐
│ 2019-11-19 14:25:48 │
└─────────────────────┘
┌───────────────now()─┐
│ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```